# Why is MySQL allowing more connections than max_connections limit?

Tags: mysql

Here's my connection stats.

```
mysql> show status like 'Conn%';
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                     | Value |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Connection_errors_accept          | 0     |
| Connection_errors_internal        | 0     |
| Connection_errors_max_connections | 0     |
| Connection_errors_peer_address    | 0     |
| Connection_errors_select          | 0     |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap         | 0     |
| Connections                       | 274   |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
```

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_%';
+----------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name              | Value                |
+----------------------------+----------------------+
| max_allowed_packet         | 16777216             |
| max_binlog_cache_size      | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size            | 104857600            |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_connect_errors         | 100                  |
| max_connections            | 151                  |
| max_delayed_threads        | 20                   |
| max_digest_length          | 1024                 |
| max_error_count            | 64                   |
| max_execution_time         | 0                    |
| max_heap_table_size        | 16777216             |
| max_insert_delayed_threads | 20                   |
| max_join_size              | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_length_for_sort_data   | 1024                 |
| max_points_in_geometry     | 65536                |
| max_prepared_stmt_count    | 16382                |
| max_relay_log_size         | 0                    |
| max_seeks_for_key          | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_sort_length            | 1024                 |
| max_sp_recursion_depth     | 0                    |
| max_tmp_tables             | 32                   |
| max_user_connections       | 0                    |
| max_write_lock_count       | 18446744073709551615 |
+----------------------------+----------------------+
```

I'm wondering why more connections are being allowed than the `max_connections` limit?
Shouldn't mysql refuse more connections or does it slowly prune old ones? From logs it appears that latter is true?

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log
2020-12-15T07:21:59.253969Z 60 [Note] Aborted connection 60 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.253979Z 57 [Note] Aborted connection 57 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.253994Z 56 [Note] Aborted connection 56 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.254119Z 58 [Note] Aborted connection 58 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.254136Z 54 [Note] Aborted connection 54 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.254143Z 59 [Note] Aborted connection 59 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.254154Z 61 [Note] Aborted connection 61 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.254565Z 55 [Note] Aborted connection 55 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.254581Z 53 [Note] Aborted connection 53 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-12-15T07:21:59.254593Z 62 [Note] Aborted connection 62 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Does this mean it doesn't matter about closing old connections if the data is no longer required as mysql will slowly prune these anyway?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after a minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
AND Optional helpful information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to reduce aborted connections.

Comment: Connections is the count since instance started.  Max_used_connections is max used concurrent connections at some point in time.  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like 'max_used_con%'; could show you the count and date and time of the highest concurrent usage (depending on your version of MySQL - newer may display Time of Day).

Comment: Your question - Does this mean it doesn't matter about closing old connections if the data is no longer required as mysql will slowly prune these anyway? - At expiration of wait_timeout (seconds) a connection would be terminated if idle.  Another topic - 2020-12-15T07:21:59.253969Z 60 [Note] Aborted connection 60 to db: 'my_db' user: 'my_user' host: 'my_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets) - is an indication net_read_timeout is too short (seconds). You may want to look at connect_timeout (seconds) as well and give your system additional seconds to avoid read timeouts.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the parameter you should look at to see how many connections were handled at the same time is *Max_used_connections*.

The Connections field should act as a counter of connections since the last restart.

> Connections
>
> The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL
> server.

> Max_used_connections
>
> The maximum number of connections that have been in use simultaneously
> since the server started.

You can refer to [this SE answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278839/how-to-increase-max-used-connections) and [the documentation](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mysql/how-show-open-database-connections-mysql/) to deep further.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the number of active connections. `Connections` is the number of connection attempts successful or not. You need to look at `Threads_connected` number. You can also check connections using `netstat` and filter on mysql port.

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7432241/471547) a similar post from stackoverlow.

Comment: Furthermore, it is the number Connections _since startup_.  That is, it is a counter.